# wls-maven-plugin:deploy shared library

Tags: maven, weblogic12c

I've migrate from weblogic-maven-plugin (10.3) to wls-maven-plugin(12.1) and encountred problem with deploying shared library.

Problem is wls-maven-plugin don't pass to Weblogic.Deployer library flag. For weblogic-maven-plugin i have same conf:

```
<plugin> 
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>10.3.6.0</version> 
                <configuration> 
                    <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                    <user>${weblogic.username}</user> 
                    <password>${weblogic.password}</password> 
                    <upload>true</upload>                                             
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>                                         
                    <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                    <isLibrary>true</isLibrary>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There element isLibrary shows plugin to pass -library flag that invokes Weblogic.Deployer.

After migrate to wls plugin:

```
<plugin> 
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
                <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>12.1.1.0</version> 
                <configuration> 
                    <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                    <user>${weblogic.username}</user> 
                    <password>${weblogic.password}</password> 
                    <middlewareHome>${env.MW_HOME}</middlewareHome>
                    <upload>false</upload> 
                    <action>deploy</action>                   
                    <remote>false</remote> 
                    <isLibrary>true</isLibrary>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>                         <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source> 
                    <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> 
                </configuration>                   
</plugin>
```

But wls plugin don't pass -library flag to Weblogic.Deployer and as result jar deployed with type unknown so my applications can't use library because don't found it.

Note: If i doing deploying manually with Weblogic.Deployer all works fine - so my manifest and weblogic-application.xml files should be correct.

Comment: Have you tried using the tag <weblogic.Deployer.isLibrary> instead? I haven't tried it before: https://java.net/projects/weblogic-examples/sources/weblogic-11g-user-examples/content/jeffrey.west/coherence-examples/common/pom.xml

Comment: No, it's just property that used for <isLibrary> in weblogic-maven-plugin and it works fine for it but not for wls-maven-plugin.

Comment: Interesting. Comparing the new version to the old at these 2 links: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/maven.htm#CHEJAEDA vs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/maven_deployer.htm#DEPGD383 you can see that the "library" boolean is no longer a deploy option. Please post if you figure out a way around it or what tag you are supposed to be using.

Comment: yes, but weblogic.deployer is supports deploy library. So i see 2 ways to solve problem. 1 - using wlst script for deploy (using wls:wlst + python script with parameters to deploy), 2 - use ant task. Maven plugins is make me sad.

Comment: then what do you use to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is wls:wlst. Call own wlst script (should be write by self - it simple) and pass parameters from maven such deployment source, url, user/password (using WLST command deploy we can pass is library parameter). It's work's well but looks bad at my point of view. Also, i think it could be done using ant task and call weblogic.deployer (anyway maven plugin and wlst call weblogic deployer application - it's just are wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to follow:

1. identify the oracle-maven-sync pom file and jar. Edit the pom file to your maven version. Install them:
   mvn -e install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.jar
2. add to your repository the following dependencies:
   jdom-1.1
   maven-artifact
   maven-compat
   maven-plugin-api
   commons-codec-1.6
   commons-io-2.2
3. Create a folder on your local machine where you put the following Weblogic dependencies:

```
weblogic_dependencies
                     |
                     --wlserver
                               |
                               --server
                                       |
                                       --lib
                                            -- weblogic.jar
                     |
                     --modules
```

(copy the wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar and all the files under wlserver/modules folder from a weblogic installation). Set MW_HOME to point to the **weblogic_dependencies** folder.

1. Run the following command from a machine where you have an installation of Weblogic:
   mvn -e -X -U com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DserverId=archiva_repository_id_from_maven_config_xml -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=%MW_HOME%
2. mvn -U archetype:crawl -Dcatalog=c:.m2\archetype-catalog.xml
3. deploy on your artifacts repository the wls-maven-plugin (see [Oracle documentation for that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/maven.htm#CHEIHIEH)!).

   - Remote deploy without middlewareHome parameter (might not work):

     > mvn clean package com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:deploy -Dadminurl=t3://admin_server_ip:7001 -Duser=weblogic_user -Dpassword=weblogic_pass -Dtargets=SRV_7011 -Dupload=true -Dname=maven_project_id
   - Remote deploy using the -DmiddlewareHome=%MW_HOME% parameter:

     > mvn clean package com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:deploy -Dadminurl=t3://admin_server_ip:7001 -Duser=weblogic_user -Dpassword=weblogic_pass -Dtargets=SRV_7011 -Dupload=true -Dname=maven_project_id -Dverbose=true -DmiddlewareHome=%MW_HOME%

Answer (score 0):

in maven plugin there is no "isLibrary" true tag to deploy as library

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's more simple than the provided answers.

By looking closely the [Oracle Documentation Page](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG883) you can see that there is a configuration option `library` which states that: *Deploy as a shared Java EE library or optional package.*

This setting also needs the  `artifactLocation` option.

The code below works smoothly and deploys the CommonLibs module as a library:

```
<build>
            <finalName>CommonLibs</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>12.2.1.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <user>USER_NAME</user>
                        <password>PASS_WORD</password>
                        <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                        <artifactLocation>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</artifactLocation>
                        <library>true</library>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>up</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```